# Cannot override Devise passwords controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need my Rails app to redirect to the home page after I submit the email to send me reset password instructions. Devise, by default renders the sign in form after entering the email.

So I am trying to override the `Devise::PasswordsController` and change its `redirect_to`, but no success. In fact, I don't think Rails is even taking in my class. It could be a very stupid mistake but I have been at it for half a day with no success.

I took the idea to override the passwords controller from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1067).

Here's my controller:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  protected
  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    root_url
  end
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:passwords => "passwords"}
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

I would like to mention that I have overridden Devise's Registations and Sessions Controllers in the same app, and they seem to work fine.

Comment: what devise version are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be possible to override the controller with the latest version of Devise (2.1.2).

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    ..override method here..
  end
end
```

And in `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'passwords', .. }
```

You can check with `rake routes` if Rails uses the derived `PasswordsController` instead of the original one, the routes should for instance contain `passwords#new` instead of `devise/passwords#new`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to mention your changes in the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions", :passwords => "passwords"}
```